# Remembering CSS left, top, right, bottom

Tags: css

When using CSS what little tricks have you done to remember (perhaps a saying?) the order of left, top, right, bottom when defining combined CSS attributes such as border, margin and padding.

I'm forever forgetting and Google seems populated with crap like W3Schools.

Comment: How is w3schools.com "crap"? It's easier on the eyes to read their [CSS3 Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_reference.asp) than the [W3C CSS 3 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/) document...

Comment: @danlefree See [W3Fools](http://w3fools.com/) for a long list of complaints. (Though I'm not aware of them being wrong anywhere as regards this particular question.)

Comment: Danlefee, see Su's response. w3schools is a satan on promoting learning and resources on HTML/CSS/JS. A movement is ongoing to get the crap dropped from page 1 google.

Comment: I wonder why nobody mentioned North, East, South, West. It's equivalent to clockwise, but hey :).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

They all go [clockwise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clockwise), starting from top.

Comment: Except background positioning (which seems a little relevant in this case), opting for left offset first, then top offset second.

Comment: @Marcel, very true, which explains why I always get that one wrong the first time.

Comment: background positioning is ordered for `x-y` coordinates which is more reasonable when you're using numeric values, rather than `left top`.

Answer (score 20):

CSS is trouble. T-R-B-L  Top-Right-Bottom-Left

Comment: Bah, beaten to the punch. A sporting +1.

Answer (score 8):

I remember it by visualising a clock face: starting at 12 o'clock (top), then moving to 3 o'clock (right), then 6 o'clock (bottom) and finally 9 o'clock (left).

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the straightforward winding analogy, I offer another mnemonic: **Top, Right, Bottom, Left** gives the initialism **TRBL**, pronounced **terrible**—or **trouble** if you like. (Hey, even **treble** gives me trouble as a baritone.) It fits in well with CRAP (Contrast, Repetition, Alignment, Proximity), the four principles of sound Web design.

Comment: CRAP.  Well done, sir

Answer (score 2):

### practice

I don't recall ever using any special *method* of memorization for this little tidbit. I do know I learned they were set in the clockwise order from the top, but then I proceeded to write a lot of CSS.

When you do a task repeatedly there is a tendency to memorize the details for efficiency, so at this point:

1. all
2. top&bottom right&left
3. top right&left bottom
4. top right bottom left

is second nature. Just like:

```
border: <width> <style> <color>;
```

and

```
background: <color> <image> <repeat> <attachment> <position>;
```